# Getting the error: expected ‘)’ before ‘idSubject’

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a programme in c but I keep getting the same two errors. The errors I get are:

```
 error: expected ‘)’ before ‘idSubject’
         printf("%d" idSubject);
```

and the other one:

```
 format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void averageMark (idSubjectE) {
    typedef enum {FALSE,TRUE} bool;

    int i;
    float acum;
    int idChair;
    int idSubject;
    int numEst;
    float mark;
    bool found=FALSE;

    scanf("%d", &idChair);
    printf ("%d", idChair);
    scanf("%d", &idSubject);

    while (idSubject!=0) {
        scanf("%d", &numEst);
        if (idSubject==idSubjectE) {
            printf("%d" idSubject);
            found=TRUE;
            for (i=1; i<numEst*2; i++) {
                if (i%2==0){
                    scanf("%f", &mark);
                    acum=acum+mark;
                }
            }
            printf("%f", acum/(float)numEst);
        }
        scanf("%d", &idSubject);
    }
}


int main(){
    averageMark(12);
}
```

I've been trying and trying but I can't find the mistake,

Answer (score 5):

change `printf("%d" idSubject);` to `printf("%d",  idSubject);` notice the `,`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find it!

Comment: @Patricia you're welcome. Next time, just look harder. :-)